# jsrsasign: unsupported private key alg: rsa

Tags: javascript, sha1, rsa

Obtengo el siguiente error al ejecutar el script:

> uncaught exception: Signature: unsupported private key alg: rsa

esto ocurre usando la variable 'pempublic' pero si uso la variable 'pemprivate' el error ya no ocurre y se genera correctamente el firmado.

¿Qué he probado?
Buscando en Google encontré 3 resultados relevantes;

1. Que tal vez la llave está mala; la extraje desde una web y desde openssl, siempre me dio el mismo resultado, yo descartaría este error.
2. Otro dice que sig.init() hacia falta, ya lo agregué y nada.
3. El tercero dice que "You cannot, however, sign a JWT with a public key(...)" este no se si aplica a lo que estoy realizando

Nota: no se preocupen por las llaves que son de prueba, no hay información comprometida ;)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var pemprivate = '-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----'
  var pempublic = '-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----'
  $('#pem').val(pempublic);
  $('#btn-submit').click(function() {
    var key = KEYUTIL.getKey(pempublic);
    var sig = new KJUR.crypto.Signature({
      'alg': 'SHA1withRSA'
    });
    sig.init(key);
    sig.updateString('{"idUsuario":"196682"}');
    var hSigVal = sig.sign();
    var base64 = hexToBase64(hSigVal);
    $('#response').val(base64);
  });
});

function hexToBase64(str) {
  return btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null,
    str.replace(/\r|\n/g, "").replace(/([\da-fA-F]{2}) ?/g, "0x$1 ").replace(/ +$/, "").split(" ")));
}
```

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto; background-color: #222222;
  padding:2rem;
  color: #777777;
}

.form-control {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0.5rem;
}

.form-control input#btn-submit {
  background-color: #FF0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jsrsasign/8.0.12/jsrsasign-all-min.js"></script>


<div class="container">
  <h3>Generate Key</h3>
  <hr/>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>llave: </label><br />
    <input id="pem" type="text" name="fname" class="form-control" />
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>respuesta: </label><br />
    <input id="response" type="text" name="lname" class="form-control" />
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <a id="btn-submit" class="btn btn-danger">Calcular</a>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: te recomiendo cambiar tu llave privada

Comment: Gracias, ¿pero la cambio por? ¿que le hago?